# Can't get 2 player local on keyboard

Tags: pc, overcooked-2

I've been playing Overcooked 1. I attached a Bluetooth keyboard to my laptop. This means 2 players can play (using different keys but at least we're not restricted to sharing a single keyboard). In other words, player 1 will use ASDW keys to move, whereas player 2 can use the cursor keys.

I've just bought Overcooked 2 and was hoping to do the same - what I've read shows it's possible and designed to be this way!

In the game, I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to load up the menu, open the controls screen and choose 2 keyboards.

I load the game, and I see 2 characters. However, only 1 of the characters has a blue circle underneath, and both ASDW and the cursor keys move a single character.

If we press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> (I think it's <kbd>CTRL</kbd>), the selected chef changes, but we only get to control 1 chef at a time!

What am I doing wrong? We'd like to play locally, 2 players, using 2 keyboards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out, you need to do this from the very first screen, where the truck is! In the bottom right, there is a "box" with the option to add another player (by pressing E on the keyboard)

This is the screen (although in the screen below, it shows you need to press <kbd>Y</kbd>)

[image]